# what is the difference between layer.add and layer.draw in kineticjs?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to develop a game using the kineticjs canvas elements.
For that an issue occurred and i was advised to take layer.draw.

But i don't know what it does,although it worked.
I tried looking this up ,didn't get any satisfactory results.
And please provide a good example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple explanation

Suppose there is a object named **Rectangle**. Now i want to add this object to my layer so that it can be drawn there meaning so that it can be visible on screen.For this step i use layer.add. Now I have added a new object i.e. **Rectangle** to my layer which implies that layer has now been modified. For the **Rectangle** object to be visible, it must be drawn on the screen.So layer.draw() is written.

Here layer is parent of object **Rectangle** because **Rectangle** resides in layer. Therefore for **Rectangle** to be visible layer must be drawn. Hope you get this.........

Comment: So if i dont provide layer.draw();
The Rectangle wont be visible on the screen,but it will be on the layer?

Comment: yes........the object will be added to the layer but it won't be visible without layer.draw()

Comment: So For **every** object i add onto the layer,i have to provide layer.draw to make it visible?

Comment: No, first you add all the required objects to layer.....then write layer.draw(). Try it...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429304/create-multiple-kinetic-js-circle-objects-randomly-and-move-them?noredirect=1#comment32346676_21429304

Can u take a look at this too.